# Getting a really strange logic error which I don't understand

Tags: c#

This code is supposed to output lines which say

trex (2 legged) dinosaur (extinct)

For a list of animals taken from a file.
If the animal isn't extinct, it is skipped by the if statement.

Everything works fine, except for the last bit, which should say (extinct).

Instead it said "true" or "false" depending on how I set up the isExtinct property.

Now I've put an if statement into the isExtinct property to output "extinct" but I get an error post compilation

```
Stacktrace:


Native stacktrace:

mono() [0x8105b4a]
mono() [0x8153274]
mono() [0x806a20b]
[0x777b940c]
mono() [0x8153224]
mono() [0x806a20b]
[0x777b940c]
[0x7744c667]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]
[0x7744c66c]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Code below

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {

        StreamReader input = new StreamReader ("animals.txt");

        while (!input.EndOfStream) {    
            string line = input.ReadLine ();
            string[] data = line.Split (',');
            if (data [3] == "true") {
                Animal myAnimal = new Animal (data[0], Convert.ToInt32(data[1]), data[2], Convert.ToBoolean(data[3]));
                Console.WriteLine (myAnimal);
                }
        }
    }
}
}

public class Animal
{
    string species;
    int legs;
    string genus;
    bool extinct;

    public Animal (string species, int legs, string genus, bool extinct)
    {
        this.species = species;
        this.legs = legs;
        this.genus = genus;
        this.extinct = extinct;
    }

    public string Species{ get; set;}
    public int Legs{ get; set;}
    public string Genus{ get; set;}
    public string isExtinct{ 
        get
        {
            return isExtinct;
        }
        set 
        {
            if (extinct == true) {
                isExtinct = "extinct";
            } else {
                isExtinct = "";
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString(){
        return String.Format("{0} ({1} legged) {2} ({3})", species, legs, genus, isExtinct);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: first guess is isextinct surely you just need a getter.. using the "set" info, eg return "extinct" if true and "" if empty

Comment: You get a `StackOverflowException` because the getter for `isExtinct` returns `isExtinct` (the same property) leading to an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property logic was wrong - you don't want two separate writable properties and your syntax incorrect.

Try this :

```
public string isExtinct { 
        get
        {
            if (extinct == true) {
                return "extinct";
            } else {
                return "";
            }        
        }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I had to add set{} to the end. For some reason, C# won't allow an empty set; statement. God I miss Java!

Comment: @hggohh - C# allows a property without a `set`.  Did you get an error?

Answer (score 2):

**Quick Fix**

Well that `isExtinct` property looks like a problem... try this one:

```
public string isExtinct
{
    get { return extinct ? "extinct" : "" }
}
```

That should fix it, but I would say you probably want to consider a cleanup...

---

**Clean Up**

For example, I would argue not having the getter at all. Just do the logic in your `ToString` method (as that is likely the only place that will need to use it anyway), then you can make the brackets conditional too. Something like:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string result = String.Format("{0} ({1} legged) {2}", species, legs, genus);
    if(extinct)
        result += " (extinct)";

    return result;
}
```

---

**Suggested Code**

In addition, your properties `Species`, `Legs`, and `Genus` don't have any use, they are not tied to your fields anyway. I would suggest removing the fields and stick with just the 4 properties:

```
public string Species{ get; set;}
public int Legs{ get; set;}
public string Genus{ get; set;}
public string IsExtinct { get; set;}

public Animal (string species, int legs, string genus, bool isExtinct)
{
    Species = species;
    Legs = legs;
    Genus = genus;
    IsExtinct = isExtinct;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    string result = String.Format("{0} ({1} legged) {2}", Species, Legs, Genus);
    if(IsExtinct )
        result += " (extinct)";

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I agree with this, and normally wouldn't apply logic within a property, but I'd been instructed to here. Coming from java, I'd just have added a method to compare the 2 then piped the output through 
...public override String toString(){
}